# Why can't I get the size of network shared folder? by powershell

Tags: powershell, network-share

I've already know a sharespace path: \sharespace\test1

I used this line to get the latest update folder under this path:

```
$lastbuild=get-childitem $var.droppath.TrimEnd()|where-object {$_.name -match "10."} |Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$lastbuild.fullname.TrimEnd()
```

what I got is `\\sharespace\test1\10.0.1212.1`

How can I get this folder's size? I used the following code, but only get the totalsize of its parent path`\\sharespace\test1`

```
$mapbuild.mapNetworkDrive("u:",$lastbuild.fullname.TrimEnd())

$fsobuild = new-Object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject

$dobuild = $fsobuild.getdrive("u:")

Write-host "Size of latestbuild:"

$dobuild.totalsize
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like exactly what you need: [Scripting Guy article on getting folder size](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx)

I think it's important to note that powershell can typically handle UNC paths natively, so there's no need to map a drive. You should be able to do something like this:

```
$fsobuild = new-Object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject
"{0:N2}" -f (($fsobuild.GetFolder($lastbuild.Fullname).Size) / 1MB) + " MB"
```